# Automatically update graph - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an automatically updating graph.
This is what I am tring to do:

I am updating my data every day. So let's say I have the number 3000. I want today's date linked with that number.

So on 27-10 - 3000. And I want to add data every day. So on 28-10 it's 3010. etc. etc.

But I want to do this automatically. So every day the graph automatically adds the new data with current date.

I am unfamiliar with graphs and no clue how to do this. The only thing I know is the function TODAY() and that the data is always in a single cell: I8.

Any Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a dynamic named range for your data (using OFFSET to dynamically include all new values). Example: http://analystcave.com/excel-dynamic-named-range/
2. Create a pivot table based on that data
3. Make a macro for refreshing the Pivot Table when data is updated (can record it with Macro Recorder) e.g.

See example below:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
```

You can add this macro to the ActiveSheet change event or better even add a button to refresh the chart.